# How to extract specific string until blank space/next line from a text in Oracle?

Tags: regexp-substr

I am trying to extract the following from the text field using Regrex in Oracle.

- For example

"This is example,

and this really a example :h,j,j,j,j,

l     //Updated question , as this letter is on the next line

now this is a disease:yes"

I am expecting a result as `h,j,j,j,j,l`, but if I use

`REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_field,'example :[^:]+,') AS Result`

I am getting `example:h,j,j,j,j`
But I am not getting the last letter 'l' like above and I am guessing that's because it's on the next line.Also, if I want the string "disease:yes" only, that will be so helpful as well. Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are getting is because your pattern includes the word 'example' and ends with a comma, leaving out the ending 'l'.  Try this form instead.  Note the example is shown using a Common table Expression (CTE).  The WITH statement creates the table called tbl which just sets up test data, kind of like a temp table.  This is also a great way to set up data when asking a question.  This form of the REGEXP_SUBSTR() function uses a captured group, which is the set of characters after the string 'example:' until the end of that line in the multi-line field.  From this you should be able to get the other string you are after.  Give it a go.

```
WITH tbl(text_field) AS (
  SELECT 'This is example,

and this really a example :h,j,j,j,j,l

now this is a disease:yes' FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_field,'example :(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Result
FROM tbl;

RESULT     
-----------
h,j,j,j,j,l

1 row selected.
```

Edit based on new info.  Since that last letter could be on it's own line, you'll need to allow for the newline.  Use the 'n' flag to REGEXP_REPLACE() which allows the newline to match in the usage of the dot (match any character) symbol in regex.  We switch to REGEXP_REPLACE as we'll need to return multiple capture groups.  Here the WITH sets up 2 rows, one with an embedded newline in the data and one without.  The capture groups are (going left to right) 1-the data after "example :" and ending in a comma, 2-the optional newline and 3-the next single character. Then replace the entire data with captured groups 1 and 3 (leaving out the newline).
NOTE this is very specific to the case of only 1 character on the following line.

```
WITH tbl(ID, text_field) AS ( 
  SELECT 1, 'This is example,
and this really a example :h,j,j,j,j,
l
now this is a disease:yes'  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'This is example,
and this really a example :h,j,j,j,j,l
now this is a disease:yes'  FROM dual
) 
SELECT ID,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(text_field, '.*example :(.*,)('||CHR(10)||')?(.).*', '\1\3', 1, 1, 'n') AS Result 
FROM tbl; 


        ID RESULT      
---------- ------------
         1 h,j,j,j,j,l 
         2 h,j,j,j,j,l 

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gary, the reason I beleive is due to the last character being on the next line , For example :

WITH tbl(text_field) AS (
  SELECT 'This is example,

and this really a example :h,j,j,j,j,
l  //if the character is in next line, I missing this letter

now this is a disease:yes' FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_field,'example :(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Result
FROM tbl;

can we use '||CHR(10)||' ?

Comment: @RahulRao That criteria was not mentioned in your original post.  Please edit your original post to add that.

Comment: Is that last letter ALWAYS on the next line? Could there be a variable number of letters on the next line?  Could you edit the OP to show some real data?

Comment: Yes, the last letter is always on the next line , followed by some text on next line. For example :
WITH tbl(ID, text_field) AS ( 
  SELECT 1, 'This is example,
and this really a example :h,j,j,j,j,
l
now this is a disease:yes'
this is some random string upto 300 characters more
which might have text not in the same format.'  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'This is example,
and this really a example :h,j,j,j,j,l
now this is a disease:yes'  FROM dual
) 
SELECT ID,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(text_field, '.*example :(.*,)('||CHR(10)||')?(.).*', '\1\3', 1, 1, 'n') AS Result 
FROM tbl;

Comment: @RahulRao Glad to help but the comment section has no formatting so your examples are better off in the original post.